# How to use Geolocation API of google on itel A16 device?

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

I have trouble getting latitude and longitude on Itel A16 device (Android 8.1.0). I have used the following code, which works fine based on my test on other devices and emulators. But not on [Itel A16](https://www.gizmochina.com/product/itel-a16-plus/) I would appreciate any help to fix this so that the Toast can show device location.

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double MyLong = location.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " latitude: " + MyLat + " longitude: " + MyLong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }

            };

            //Location test
            if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(getContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) , following Android Developers instructions